# create a websocket connection and disconnection routine

Tags: qt, websocket

I am reviewing an example of a websokect client, however I could not execute a routine after the return a.exe ();
I explain I need to perform other routines, however if I do not place return a.exe (); it does not make the connection and it continues with the code, that would have to do so that this does not happen?

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "sslechoclient.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

for (;;;){
    SslEchoClient client(QUrl(QStringLiteral("wss://localhost:1234")));

    Q_UNUSED(client);

//my serial reading application

}

    return a.exec();
}
```

Cpp

```
#include "sslechoclient.h"
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtWebSockets/QWebSocket>
#include <QCoreApplication>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

SslEchoClient::SslEchoClient(const QUrl &url, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::connected, this, &SslEchoClient::onConnected);
    connect(&m_webSocket, QOverload<const QList<QSslError>&>::of(&QWebSocket::sslErrors),
            this, &SslEchoClient::onSslErrors);
    m_webSocket.open(QUrl(url));
}

void SslEchoClient::onConnected()
{
    qDebug() << "WebSocket connected";
    connect(&m_webSocket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived,
            this, &SslEchoClient::onTextMessageReceived);
    m_webSocket.sendTextMessage(QStringLiteral("Hello, world!"));
}

void SslEchoClient::onTextMessageReceived(QString message)
{
    qDebug() << "Message received:" << message;
    qApp->quit();
}

void SslEchoClient::onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{
    Q_UNUSED(errors);

    // WARNING: Never ignore SSL errors in production code.
    // The proper way to handle self-signed certificates is to add a custom root
    // to the CA store.

    m_webSocket.ignoreSslErrors();
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef SSLECHOCLIENT_H
#define SSLECHOCLIENT_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>
#include <QtWebSockets/QWebSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QSslError>
#include <QtCore/QList>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QUrl>

QT_FORWARD_DECLARE_CLASS(QWebSocket)

class SslEchoClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SslEchoClient(const QUrl &url, QObject *parent = nullptr);

private Q_SLOTS:
    void onConnected();
    void onTextMessageReceived(QString message);
    void onSslErrors(const QList<QSslError> &errors);

private:
    QWebSocket m_webSocket;
};

#endif // SSLECHOCLIENT_H
```

I would be very grateful if you can help.

Comment: Hi, you should explain in more details the steps you are taking to run your application.

Comment: I have to read the serial port, ready code

nevertheless I need to create a websokect connection and send that data.
I have been working to modify the example, but I can not make the connection. that is, doing a reading cycle and later sending data to the websocket server

this is the QT example
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-sslechoclient-main-cpp.html

Comment: @Piter Why do you need `for(;;)`?. The elements of Qt need the event-loop, and that event-loop is implemented with `app.exec();`, I do not see why to use `for(;;)` which is equivalent to a while true blocks the task of Qt, What you should do is use signals that implement a state machine, if you have a heavy task you should use a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Would your application work a bit like:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QWebSocket socket;
// Your stuff
int retValue = app.exec();
// Do some other stuff
return retValue;
```

?

Comment: The socket needs the event loop to do its job so if the end of the event-loop will not work.

Comment: Add the lines of code but it has not worked, however add more information, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Piter In Qt you have to handle all the logic with signals, I recommend you read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: @eyllanesc I know, there was no code provided when I asked that question so the logic could have been: do something with the socket, once done do something else like log the result, write a file etc. which do not require any event loop but needed to be done in main for whatever reasons before exiting the application.

Comment: that you would have to include to reopen the websokect connection?, taken as reference the previous code

Comment: @Piter The question is when do you want to reopen the connection ?, you have to handle that event by means of a signal and connect it to a slot, and in that slot do your reconnection logic.

Comment: When there is data available for serial reading, how could you implement it?

Comment: Then why are you quitting the app when you received a message ? The goal of that kind of socket is to open a communication channel that you keep until all communications are done.

Comment: What would you have to add to write data continuously, while the external connection open? if in addition the data must be Json type?

Comment: Where should the data come from ? As for the JSON part, you can start with [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html)